# Installer can't remove previous version

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, installation

I use a visual studio setup & deploy project to install my components of my application. This has worked sucessfully with other applications and to allow the current version to install over the top of previous versions usually means just setting a property on the install project namely RemovePreviousVersions and setting that to true.

In this case, a windows service is installed and when I try to install the latest version I get the message "The specified service already exists". I've tried to stop the service before doing the installation.

Is there a simple way around this problem?

Comment: Did you have the services snap-in open when you tried to uninstall - I've experienced and read of other people having problems (un)installing services when this was open.

Comment: That didn't work - but appreciate the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to manually uninstall the service, then install it again.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha(VS.80).aspx